# Save part of a String from a word to a different word

Tags: java, string

So, I'm still learning Java and I am curious about extracting information from Strings and and assigning the information to a variable.

Let's for example say, I have the following String:

```
{"my_books_are_all_organized","yes_sir_yes_they_are"}
```

Then I wish to make a new String that that only contains this part:

```
my_books
```

For example a String variable called whatIsOgranized, which only held the text "my_books", would have to gather all the information from the symbols:

```
{"
```

To the symbols:

```
_are
```

Everything in between those sets of symbols are to be stored in the whatIsOrganized String. So when I run:

```
System.out.println(whatIsOrganized);
```

It gives me:

```
my_books
```

Is this possible in Java? Could anyone show me how my above example would be coded?

Comment: Yes, but under which criteria do you want to locate the substring in the greater one? Index? Match it by RegEx? ...?

Comment: Have you read the javadoc of the java.lang.String class? If not, then do it.

Comment: @tilois Well, um, in fear of giving a stupid answer, I'm not sure. I just wonder if I got that String, could I store parts of the information in a new String. Updated my question, last line, if anyone could show me how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes, and the [String class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) do it well.

I suggest to learn Java from the [official tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/TOC.html), the chapter for Strings is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/manipstrings.html).

For a more powerful method to extract parts of string, the [Regular Expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) may be used.
The main class to deal with RE is [java.util.regex.Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and their official tutorial is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/). Another tutorial resource is [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html).

Answer (score 1):

there is method in String Object in Java :

String    substring(int beginIndex)
          Returns a new string that is a substring of this string.
 String     substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)
          Returns a new string that is a substring of this string.

which can be used as:

```
public class Test{
   public static void main(String args[]){
      String Str = new String("Welcome to Stackoverflow.com");

      System.out.print("Return Value :" );
      System.out.println(Str.substring(10) );

      System.out.print("Return Value :" );
      System.out.println(Str.substring(10, 15) );
   }
}

Return Value : Stackoverflow.com
Return Value : Stac
```

There are more ..depending on requirement.

Comment: Yeah, see, that was something like what I was hoping for, but I am assuming I will be operating with a lot of Strings, and I wonder if its doable by searching getting everything between two sets of symbols instead of the index? Like between "e " and " S" to get the word "to" on your third line?

Comment: @ViRALiC - I think firstly if you know the String around which you want-- whatIsOrganized - then you can use-   int  indexOf(String str)
          Returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the specified substring.

Comment: @ViRALiC-- Go to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html... This will really help you.